# virtual-manager vnc connection failed

Tags: virtual-machine, vnc

I am trying to set up a virtual machine in CentOS, with virt-manager. When I was creating a new machine, i was promoted the following message.

```
Unable to complete install: 'internal error Process exited while reading console log
output: char device redirected to /dev/pts/1
inet_listen_opts: bind(ipv4,127.0.0.1,5900): Cannot assign requested address
inet_listen_opts: FAILED
Failed to start VNC server on `127.0.0.1:0'
'
```

virtual machine should not be using VNC? Is there a way to disable this setting?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have a loopback interface. Have you disabled it?
Try something like this:

```
ifconfig lo 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0 up
```